# Getting website content from different location

Tags: php, web-applications, cpanel

I am developing an online accounting project. I do not want to give my code to the clients, but I have to give control of the domain to them. How can I configure the application such that it uses the Database from my client's domain and the application from my own domain ?

For eg : my application domain in www.a.com and my clients domain are b.com, c.com and so on. 
a.com holds the application source code and b.com holds the database.

Now what I want to do is get the application code from a.com and get database from b.com whenever b.com is opened.

Or is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: if your white list your ip for db connection remotely from your domain you must be able to do that.

Comment: well i have allowed all ip's for remote access for the time being.

Comment: u said your client has got the database so they have to give you permission for your domain.

Comment: i meant from my client's domain..

Comment: then you must be able to use .$db = new PDO(mysql:host=clientip;dbname=test, $username, $password);

Comment: Are your clients aware of these settings..?? If they are not then it's unethical..

Comment: well that's the problem. client does not want to share database and i do not want to share my code. what could be the solution which works both ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into setting a CNAME record through your domain name's administration settings and using sub-domains, perhaps.

Here's more information from Google http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283 and Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record